# Coding a Menubar in one place only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a [website for a law office](http://www.richardmeinderslaw.com/).  Each page will have the same basic layout as you see here:  The same title bar, the same menu bar on the left, and the same footer.  The only thing that will change from page to page is the content section.

My first approach would be to duplicate the code for these common elements for each content page.  Then, in the future, if things need to be changed on those bars (certainly going to happen), I would have to go into each and every sub page to make the changes.

This makes the programmer in me shudder.  I have to imagine there is a way do to this without using a crazy html-programming suite.  (I'm using notepad++ right now to code).  Is there a way to write the html code for the menu bar in one place and then "source" it in, like I do with the javascript and css code?

I know something like this can be done with frames, but I don't want to go that route.

Comment: have you considered some server side scripting like php?

Comment: Or even [server-side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes), perhaps.

Comment: Have you considered using iframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use some PHP, it will make your life easier. Just a look on [inlude()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function, this is really what you are looking for.

You'll have a file for footer, one for header, one for the menu, and then, in you page, you can just use :

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<?php include('menu.php'); ?>

<!-- Your content somewhere here -->

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: What does the content of "header.php" look like?  Is it simply an html document?  Why the .php extension?

I'm comfortable with php (well, perl), so I may go this route (I'll have to make sure my server supports php, pretty sure it does).  

Is there any reason why this is better than server side includes, as suggested by @david in his comment to my post?

Comment: For doing only includes, and nothing else, SSI will probably be just fine.  However, PHP is much more flexible and opens up a lot of other options.  It depends on your needs.

Comment: Even though `header.php` has the `.php` extension, it can just contain regular HTML.  You can use `.html` without issue, but `.php` is common practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are restricted to using only HTML/JS for some reason, you can use jQuery's **[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** method:

```
$('#menu').load('includes/menu.html');
```

This will load the HTML from `menu.html` and place it within the `#menu` element.  However, if possible, go with something similar to what Haza suggests.

Comment: If you use this, people who don't have javascript enabled or their browser doesn't support javascript will not have a menu bar. You would also need to load the jQuery library on all pages first.

Comment: Obviously something like PHP is the right decision here, but from the wording of the question I thought it may not be an option (hence leading with a disclaimer).

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I can do whatever is the "right" way.  PHP seems to be the thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with server stuff, you could create a javascript function that creates the HTML for you and then writes it to the page. For instance

```
function writeNavigation(){
document.write("<nav>");
document.write("  <li> home <\/li>");
document.write("  <li> about <\/li>");
document.write("  <li> blog <\/li>");
document.write("</nav>");
}
```

This way, you could link to the file in the head of your HTML page like this ->

And then, you could simply call the function when the page loads like this ->

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = writeNavigation()
</script>
```

However, using this has no fallback method, so users without JavaScript will be left with no menu.